# Docker volume mount fails with the below error

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-volume

Docker volume mount fails with the below error.

I'm trying to run a container with a config file in the volume and it fails with the below errors.

```
root@ip-172-31-21-249:~/data# docker run -it -p 8080:8080 -p 29418:29418 -v /root/data:/var/gerrit/etc/ forkub
error: could not lock config file /var/gerrit/etc/gerrit.config: Permission denied
root@ip-172-31-21-249:~/data# docker run -it -p 8080:8080 -p 29418:29418 -v /root/data:/var/gerrit/etc forkub
error: could not lock config file /var/gerrit/etc/gerrit.config: Permission denied
root@ip-172-31-21-249:~/data# docker run -it -p 8080:8080 -p 29418:29418 -v /root/data/:/var/gerrit/etc forkub
error: could not lock config file /var/gerrit/etc/gerrit.config: Permission denied
root@ip-172-31-21-249:~/data# docker run -it -p 8080:8080 -p 29418:29418 -v /root/data/:/var/gerrit/etc/ forkub
error: could not lock config file /var/gerrit/etc/gerrit.config: Permission denied
root@ip-172-31-21-249:~/data# docker run -it -p 8080:8080 -p 29418:29418 -v /root/data/:/var/gerrit/etc/gerrit.config forkub
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/root/data\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/0a5356aed5a1aa1d1359912ccba7547db55b0377b3a509b898828734868e335a/merged\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/0a5356aed5a1aa1d1359912ccba7547db55b0377b3a509b898828734868e335a/merged/var/gerrit/etc/gerrit.config\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

Any suggestions on fixing this is really appreciated.

Thank you,
Anish

Comment: any comment on my answer? Did it solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the process in the container does not run as `root` but as some other user. The file belongs to `root` though and is not readable by the user that runs the process. So the process can not read the file.
So you need to make sure that the user that runs the process in the container can access those files. The easiest way would be to make `/root/data` world read-/writeable (`chmod -R 777 /root/data`) but this is obviously not the best way. The right way to do this, would be to find out which user is running the process in the container and change the ownership of `/root/data` and everything in it to that user.

The problem with `docker run -it -p 8080:8080 -p 29418:29418 -v /root/data/:/var/gerrit/etc/gerrit.config forkub` is, that you are trying to mount a directory `/root/data` to a file. This does not work.